# Customise voicemail message based on caller

Tags: iphone, ios, voicemail

Is it possible to programme a specific voicemail message to be used when an individual telephone number calls me? I would like to have my general voicemail message for all calls except one from a client with dementia who needs a difference message to reassure her.

I am using an iPhone 6 running iOS 12.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. This is very helpful.  I wasn't sure if there was a phone based solution or whether to go to my service provider.  I will see if they can help.  I didn't know about Google voice and will explore this too.

Answer (score 8):

Voicemail is a carrier feature and currently, there are no carriers as far as I am aware that permit you to store multiple greetings.

Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3841850?answerId=3841850021#3841850021

> Voicemail is a carrier feature & your greeting is stored on their servers. I'm not aware of any carrier, anywhere, that permits multiple greetings.

Comment: It seems redundant to quote a thread and then state it nearly verbatim.

Comment: @Thunderforge This practice helps reduce link rot; if that link is ever deprecated and the thread deleted/no longer available, the quote will still be there.

Comment: My point was that linking to the site and quoting it makes sense, but then adding your own summary on top of that using almost the exact same words (e.g. “voicemail is a carrier feature”) seems redundant.

Answer (score 5):

The only option that I have used for this is [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com), which is free (I believe it’s only available in the USA). You can definitely make different voicemails for different groups (and put just one person in a group if you want).

Thanks to a comment by @MonkeyZeus, according to http://itstillworks.com/forward-voicemail-google-voice-5795554.html you can forward your regular number to Google Voice so that your contacts never interact with the Google Voice number.

Comment: Why is there a "catch"? According to https://itstillworks.com/forward-voicemail-google-voice-5795554.html you can forward your regular number to Google Voice so that your contacts never interact with the Google Voice number.

Comment: That's interesting. I've never done it that way before, but then again my purpose in using Google Voice has always been to have a number I can give out that is not my actual cell phone number (so I can use GV as a filter).

Comment: I was going to write my own answer around the link I provided but I don't have any first-hand experience with GV nor call-forwarding on my cell phone. So if you would like to incorporate that link's info into your answer then I will gladly upvote.

Comment: Good thinking! Some people might miss it down here. Added. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this directly from within iOS as voicemails are generally a service provided by the phone network.

However, there are a number of 3rd party services (e.g. [You Mail](https://www.youmail.com/home/feature/custom-greetings)) you can subscribe to that claim to offer this functionality.

Unfortunately, I haven't used any of these services so cannot attest to how well they work or not.